# Making a loading screen that appears when syncing without delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've spend a lot if time on this and I can't find a perfect solution.

I'm making an App that has a Table View with a bunch of items. If you click on an item it opens a Webview controller with a webpage, there's a back button in this View.

I get the data for these items through an API I made. This may take some time so I need a loading screen while the items are loading from the API. However, when the items are synced and the last time it has synced has not been longer than X time, it shouldn't do the API call but just get it from Core Data (where it's stored after the API call).

Now I'm struggeling with the loading screen. Some requirements:

- If the data needs to be synced, the loading screen should appear directly:

  - when the App starts, or
  - when you click on the backbutton in the Webview, or
  - the App was put on the background and appears back on the foreground with the Table View as the active View
- If the data doesn't need to be synced, the Table View should appear directly in same situations as previous point
- The transition animation from the loading screen to the Table View should be Cross Dissolve.
- I'm planning to make the loading screen have a slider with some photo's, so it can't just be an overlay image

  I first tried it like this:

[image: Loading screen as push segue]

Here the loading screen is the first view after the Navigation Controller. If the data in synced, I call the segue to the Table View (in `viewWillAppear`). If the data is not synced it will wait untill it's synced. In the `viewWillAppear` method of the Table View Controller I also check if the sync needs to be done (in case you come back from Webview, or App got to foreground), if so, I call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]` (so it goes back to the loading screen).

This works good, the animation from the Webview to the loading screen goes smooth and I don't see the Table View in between. But I can't modify the animation because it's a push. So I can't have the dissolve animation.

So I tried a different approach:

[image: Loading screen with modal segues]

Over here I made Modal segues. On the one from the Table View to the loading screen I disabled the animation and the one from the loading screen to Navigation Controller I gave the Cross Disolve transition. It needs to go back to Navigation Controller because otherwise I don't have the Navigation Controller in Table View.

In Table View I check again if the data needs to be synced and if so, segue to the loading screen. However, this time I need to do this in `viewDidAppear` because the loading screen is not present yet in `viewWillAppear`, it will throw a warning when you would put the App to the background, wait untill X time has passed (so it will sync) and put the App to the foreground again. This is the warning I get:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <BWLoadingScreenViewController: 0x829e2b0> on <UINavigationController: 0x856a6b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

So I use `viewDidAppear` and I don't have the warning, however, this method also has a downside:

- When I go back from the Webview and X time has passed (so it will sync), I see the push animation go first to the Table View and then it flashes to the loading screen, pretty ugly...

Now I could of course use manual segues all over the place and before each segue check if data needs to be synced and if so segue to the loading screen instead of the other, but that would become pretty complicated for such a simple thing, and I also would like to have one universal place that checks if the sync needs to be done or not and display the loading screen or not.

Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this dilemma in a nice and clean way? Suggestions are very welcome. I'm still pretty new to iOS development so maybe you can give me some new insights. If you want more information about my setup just ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find out a way.

I found out you can have a custom segue animation while still doing a push. With the help of this little article:
http://blog.jambura.com/2012/07/05/custom-segue-animation-left-to-right-using-catransition/

Basically you make a custom segue class:

header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BWLoadingScreenSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "BWLoadingScreenSegue.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

@implementation BWLoadingScreenSegue

- (void)perform
{

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

}

@end
```

You'll need to add the QuartzCore framework to your linked frameworks to make this work. Then you can select the segue, choose 'Style' = 'Custom' and 'Segue Class' = your segue class name (with code above). Now, because of the method `pushViewController` it will still be a push, and because of the `transition.type = kCATransitionFade;` it will be a fade transition. Very nice.

You can choose more transitions, like:

```
kCATransitionMoveIn
kCATransitionPush
kCATransitionReveal
kCATransitionFade
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the loading screen (an `UIImageView` for example) to ur MasterViewController directly (who need to be a `UIViewController` and not a `UITableViewController`) and simply do like:

```
myImageView.hidden = NO;
```

or

```
myImageView.hidden = YES;
```

depending on whether you're getting your data from your API or not. You can also do multiple objects (e.g. add a `UIActivityIndicatorView`)

Comment: I'm planning to make my loading screen a slider with some photo's, so just an image won't do it